# Как сделать, чтобы анимация начиналась не с первой секунды?

Tags: ios, swift

Как сделать, чтобы анимация начиналась не с первой секунды?
Чтобы часть анимации прошла, и анимация начиналась со второй или третьей секунды?
Делаю анимацию через SKAction

Answer (score 0):

В SKAction есть метод waitForDuration, попробуй использовать её